# Does the current hashcat include CUDA?

Tags: hashcat

I've been using the old cudahashcat 2.x until I reinstalled my system. I realized I cann't find any newer release on cudahascat so I assume it is included in hashcat but when I look at their github it seems to be only the OpenCL is included. So my question being do I need to find cudahashcat mod somewhere or should I just use the official hashcat 4.x?

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely just use the latest hashcat from hashcat.net. Note that CUDA is not included and downloaded separately.

There have been many changes and improvements since 'cudaHashcat' / 'oclHashcat' / 'hashcat' (CPU) were all merged into the new unified 'hashcat'.

All devices now require OpenCL - even CPU - <strike>and CUDA is completely gone.</strike>

[Update Jan 2020: CUDA support is returning in the upcoming 6.0.0 release of hashcat. One major benefit: you will have access to *all* available GPU memory - not just 1/4 of it! The CUDA driver itself is still a separate download from NVIDIA.]

Comment: What happens if I have an older GPU/CPU that doesn't really run OpenCL (well)? I have a GF116 [GeForce GTS 450 Rev. 2] in this particular machine.

Comment: If the card is still supported by the manufacturer (current drivers), and OpenCL works generally, then hashcat should work.

Comment: No it is not supported...

Comment: Ah, bummer. Only cards supported by current drivers are supported by hashcat. (It's a little OT, but you can get a much newer card quite cheaply used - even a GTX750Ti would be significantly better, a GTX 970 should also be relatively affordable.)

Comment: @RoyceWilliams i am providing you a link dated 17-May-2019, where we can see hashcat using CUDA API for PKZIP cracking. Is there any way to use CUDA. https://twitter.com/hashcat/status/1129441728761610242?lang=en

Comment: Yep, CUDA support is returning in the upcoming 6.0.0 release of hashcat! If you can't wait, you can grab the beta (https://hashcat.net/beta/) and/or the latest GitHub (https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat)

Answer (score 3):

No, neither the [hashcat binaries download](https://hashcat.net/hashcat) nor by hashcat download via Kali Linux repositories include the Nvidia CUDA Toolkit; the Nvidia CUDA Toolkit must be downloaded separately- feel free to review my [full gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/alexanderjsingleton/d00a56a51127e73b70a2cdffcd75c9e2).  Hope that helps!

### Installing the Nvidia CUDA Toolkit 10.0

#### Installing the Nvidia CUDA Toolkit 10.0 for Ubuntu 18.04 - Option A (Recommended)

1. `sudo apt update && apt dist-upgrade -y && reboot`
2. `lspci -v`
3. `sudo apt install -y ocl-icd-libopencl1 nvidia-driver nvidia-cuda-toolkit`.
4. `nvidia-smi`
5. Run `sudo hashcat -I` or `sudo hashcat --benchmark` for benchmarks.

#### Installing the Nvidia CUDA Toolkit 10.0 for Ubuntu 18.04 - Option B

1. Go to [Nvidia CUDA Toolkit 10.0 for Ubuntu 18.04](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads).
2. Select the following Select Target Platform Window: Linux > X86_64 > Ubuntu > 18.04 > runfile (local)

   - To check your OS architecture run `uname -a` it should return "x_86_64" within the terminal display.
3. Download the Base Installer (2.0 GB) by click on the Download button.
4. Access Terminal and [close X Server to avoid errors while updating nVidia driver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25668/how-to-close-x-server-to-avoid-errors-while-updating-nvidia-driver) by running `sudo init 3`; a black-screen will appear and prompt you to enter your Ubuntu username and password- please enter.
5. After logging-in, run `cd ~/Downloads`.
6. Run `sudo sh cuda_10.0.130_410.48_linux.run`
7. Scroll down to accept the conditions by holding down the "Return" key or space-bar- upon scrolling to the bottom, type: `accept`; alternatively, you can hit 'CTRL + D' to bypass scrolling.
8. Install the CUDA 10.0 Toolkit by enter `y`
9. Do you want to Install the OpenGL Libraries `y`
10. Do you want to run nvidia-xconfig?  Enter `y`
11. Install the CUDA Toolkit? Enter `y`
12. Unless otherwise preferred, hit the "Return" key to enter the specified default absolute-path (e.g. `/usr/local/cuda-10.0`).
13. Enter `y` to install a symbolic link at `/usr/local/cuda`.
14. Enter `y` to Install the CUDA 10.0 Samples
15. Hit the "Return" key to enter CUDA Samples default location-path (e.g. `/home/alexanderjsingleton`).
16. After the install, open the X Server by running `sudo init 5`; if for whatever reason you're unable to reboot the computer after installing the CUDA 10.0 Toolkit, turn-off the computer and reboot- remember to click on the Settings icon and select "Ubuntu on wayland" before entering the username and password.
17. Access terminal and enter the following commands in sequence:

    - `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`
    - `sudo apt-get update`
    - `sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev`
    - `sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev`
18. Reboot the computer by running `sudo shutdown -r now`

Answer (score 0):

Since hashcat v6.0.0, CUDA seems to be supported. See https://hashcat.net/forum/thread-9303.html.